# Overriding django authentication with Django rest framework authentication

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I need to access a djangorestframework api but because the django server  uses CSRF token and i cant get past it. How can i configure djangorestframework to override the djangorestframework and not be redirected to login?

Im new to this so i need help.

accessing the django rest framework would be a pure python program which runs in the background of a client pc collecting data so i need to use urllib2 or request for this. any ideas?

Comment: you want CSRF. So find out how to generate a token, create a REST endpoint that delivers it. Then on the client side include that token in subsequent requests.

Answer (score 1):

The API needs to expose an authentication method for your client to use.

The `SessionAuthentication` style requires CSRF validation and is suuitable for javascript based clients, running in the context of a logged-in application. If this describes the sort of client access you're making then read the Django documentation on [CSRF and AJAX requests](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#ajax), which describes how to pass a CSRF token to a javascript based client.

Other schemes such as `TokenAuthentication` do not require CSRF validation, and will successfully authentication without passing any CSRF token.

Make sure that you know what schemes the API supports and choose the right one to use for your client access.

For more information see the [authentication documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/).

Comment: Hi @Tom, I am looking for a good example of a TokenAuthentication implementation with DRF, do you know any?